# SSIS how to use a table created in a SQL Task as destination in a following Data Flow Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

In SSIS I have a SQL Task which drops and creates a table T. Then I have a Data Flow task which needs to use T as destination to write data.

The Destination Assistant and the fast-load option needs the table T already present in the database to show it as possible destination.

Maybe I could use SQL Command as data access mode but I don't know how to access the incoming data columns from the stream.

How can I use table T as destination in the data flow task?

Comment: Can't you create the table before you use the Destination wizard? Once done, you can attempt to drop it again, but if the SQL task does that prior to pushing data upstream, you wouldn't even have to do that.

Comment: If the new table has same structure you should just truncate it. If the table has a new structure, Good luck. You probably need new separate packages and destination tables. If you have to drop and create, then delay validation is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the tablename inside a package variable, select destination type as `Tablename from variable` and use it, but make sure to set `Delay Validation` property to `True` *(change this property in the dataflow task and destination)*

*Note: when designing package T table must be found in the database to read it's structure in the destination, also if tablename is fixed can achieve this without the use of a variable*

Answer (score 0):

instead of `drop table T` in first sql task, `truncate table T` and Table t will be a permanently available as destination assistant. Hope this helps

Comment: @B House 
I specifically need to drop the table. In general I am interested on how in SSIS is possible to use a dynamically created table inside a data flow

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL Task instead of drop and create, can you just Delete or Truncate the data in table T?

Comment: I specifically need to drop the table. In general I am interested on how in SSIS is possible to use a dynamically created table inside a data flow